# In Success Toast Message we are getting record id instead of record name and it happening only for success toast message not for delete toast message

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, admin, toast

In Success Toast Message we are getting record id instead of record name and it happening only for success toast message not for delete toast message

Could you anyone guide on this ? Added two images for your reference

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, If there is no page layout assigned for record type then it couldn't pick the value. so it picks the record id.